# Program type already present: com.opencsv.CSVParser

Tags: android, opencsv

I am using opencsv gradle file for creating a csv file in android, but I am getting the following error:

```
 implementation group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.2'
```

if I comment this then my android app works fine, but when I open this from the comment and try run my application then I am getting the following error:

```
 Program type already present: com.opencsv.CSVParser$1
 Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:   com.opencsv.CSVParser$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I've found so many articles but I didn't find the solution, so please help me to sort this problem out.

Other Information :

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' 

 minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 26
```

Problem shows after I update my target version 25 to 26. but after this issue I downgrade version 26 to 25 then still same issue showing.

Comment: post your lib folder libraries.

Comment: my lib folder have only one library named : android-query-full.0.26.7.jar

Comment: Hello @AbhayKoradiya indirectly you solve my problem, i having likey same issue, my another library project conflict it with, so i solve out that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me the issue occurred when I initially added

```
implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0'
```

to my build.gradle file, failed to fully sync the gradle file, then added the opencsv-4.2.jar file in my libs folder, and changed the implementation to

```
implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.2'
```

It was fixed after removing the opencsv-4.2.jar from the libs folder, and changing the implementation back to the initial 4.0 version.
Its by no right a real solution, but it worked for now.